# Correct use of OnDOMReady function

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following on DOM ready function, if I have 2 functions that use this declaration:

```
$(document).ready(function(){my Function here});
```

Now should I use two tags, one for each function or should I declare both functions in one of these tags, both inside the: `$(document).ready(function(){my two Functions here});`?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){my Function here});
</script>
```

Thank You

Comment: What you mean by "tags"? First I thought you mean `<script>` tags  but I'm not sure. Please make it more clear in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I meant <script> tags yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two. There is no harm in it and this allows you to do modular coding. For example, it allows you to keep relevant pieces of code together.

As an example, suppose you have two JavaScript widgets, both are independent of each other, both in their own separate files, both present at different locations on the page, either of them may or may not be present on the page. Instead of creating a hodge-podge of scripts you can keep separate them like this:

```
<script>
    var ads = {};
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // do something with ads
    });
</script>

<script>
    var tracker = {};
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // do something with tracker
    });
</script>
```

Comment: One more question, what is the difference in using $(document).ready(function(){}); and using just $(function(){}); ?

Comment: No difference. One is easier on the eyes than the other :) see [jQuery.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Answer (score 1):

You can make multiple calls to `$(document).ready()` with different functions. They will all be bound to that event unless the moment you included them is after the event took place (including them via AJAX with `$.getScript()`).

You shouldn't be including your code directly in the HTML.

Stick it in one or more external files and reference them with `src`.

That way they can get cached easily and users don't re-download the same content on each page-load.

Also you can structure your different on-ready files to fulfil different purposes. One initializes external plug-ins. One runs some event bindings. One applies form validations.

Having them in different files means you can also include the files when needed. onReady.ShoppingCart.js may be needed on all pages in a shop but not on CMS pages of that shop and not on the checkout lane.

Comment: thank you for your answer.vWhat if I have a function initializing an already included script, such as this: <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.quickFlip').quickFlip();
});
</script>
. Should this script be included inside the html?

Answer (score 1):

the purpose of `ready()` (versus inline `onload=""`) is to allow binding of multiple handlers for one event.

So, just use the most simple/clear to you, it would be silly to forbid yourself to bind multiple times when the internet have fought so much to get rid of the use of inline handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Use one. Makes the code easier to manage so you can see all the functions being called in one place.

Comment: Using that principle of easy to manage if it's all in one place makes for big functions (many lines of code, many conditional branches and subbranches). Big functions are an indicator of lack of modularization of the code and lack of encapsulation of concerns. Which in turn leads to spaghetti code. The correct term for OOP spaghetti code is Spaghetti and meatballs :-).

Comment: I don't mean write the functions here - put the function calls here. A function call is usually one line? It also depends on the project.

Comment: I didn't mean adding the function code entirely there either. But in complex projects or long time maintenance projects requirements tend to stack-up and you start needing to bind some events only in some cases and needing to pass some parameters for some types of objects and some other parameters for other types of objects. You end up writing `if`s there to manage this and they turn into spaghetti fast.